# Move Store on U1 Android Music App

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

On the Samsung Galaxy S2, there is an internal SD storage mounted as `/SDCARD`, and the external SD is mounted to `/SDCARD/usbStore`.

Is it possible to run the Ubuntu One Music app on `/SDCARD/usbStore/subsonic` rather than `/SDCARD/subSonic`?

Comment: The External storage (physical SD Card) is mounted in /sdcard/external_sd/ not in /usbstore, that's a folder for a Samsung bundled application.

Answer (score 2):

Sure! We can make that an option :)

Just confirmed this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-music/+bug/721815

Please follow it for updates :)

Comment: Could you possibly mark this as an answer :)? I think you've been satisfied with the app update :) Thanks!